# What is the common design pattern for an arbitrary number of database calls in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I am new to NodeJS and I confused by the async-by-default nature of it.

Assume I have an API where people send strings of words:

```
Health Initiatives

Global Steel Slate

Vera Cruz Taste Bud Delight
```

I need to get all documents in the database that have any of these words. So I need to do 2 database queries for the first string, 3 for the second string, and 5 queries for that last string.

I don't get how that should look in my code. In a language such as PHP I would simply break the string into an array, and then loop over the array, make a database call, and aggregate the results, then send the results to whoever called the API. So in PHP:

```
$results = array();
$pieces = explode(" ", "Global Steel Slate");
for ($i=0; $i < count($pieces); $i++) {
  $piece = $pieces[$i];
  $document = database_call($piece); 
  array_push($results, $document);
}
return $results;
```

How do I do handle this situation in NodeJS? How can I do an arbitrary number of database calls and then aggregate the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, you can do it in one query:

```
select * from mytable where
    mydata like '%Health%' or
    mydata like '%Initiatives%' or
    mydata like '%Global%' or
    mydata like '%Steel%' or
    mydata like '%Slate%' or
    mydata like '%Vera%' or
    mydata like '%Cruz%' or
    mydata like '%Taste%' or
    mydata like '%Bud%' or
    mydata like '%Delight%';
```

Incidentally, this would also significantly improve PHP code.

For handling multiple async operations, all possible design patterns are covered by the async.js library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async or if you prefer promises the promise-based async-q library (which implements most of the functions in async.js): https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q

For example, with async.js if you want to query all those words in parallel you can do:

```
async.each([
    'Health','Initiatives','Global',
    'Steel','Slate', 'Vera', 'Cruz',
    'Taste', 'Bud', 'Delight'
], asyncFunction, doneFunction)
```

If you want to limit it to 3 connections you can do:

```
async.eachLimit([
    'Health','Initiatives','Global',
    'Steel','Slate', 'Vera', 'Cruz',
    'Taste', 'Bud', 'Delight'
], 3, asyncFunction, doneFunction)
```

If each request feeds data to the next request there's `async.waterfall`, if you want to process each async process one at a time there's `async.eachSeries` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I can't do one big LIKE query because I'm actually running the queries against AWS ElasticSearch, which has a hard limit of 10,000 documents in the return. If each word might match 1,000 to 2,000 documents, then given enough words we would go over the 10,000 limit. So each word needs to be a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't do the same thing? First of all which database will you use?

You can receive a string and split it and then do multiple database queries in parallel (It's much faster)

```
const words = value.split(' ');

const listOfQueries = words.map((word) => {
    return database.query('SQL QUERY word'); //should return a promise
});

const results = await Promise.all(listOfQueries);
```

or you can do it sequencial:

```
const words = value.split(' ');
let results = [];

for(let i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
   results.push(await database.query('SQL QUERY word')); //should return a promise
}

//DO stuff with results...
```

I hope it helps :)

Since you are new in Node.js and probably you are using MySql I really recommend you to use knex.js + Mysql Driver (http://knexjs.org/ + https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) it's full promise compatible!